# Having some doubts on how to name my Vue.js components and some more

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm gonna try to not make this too long and just shoot some questions which have been bothering me for some time:

1. If a view is displaying 2 different children components based on the
   URL via a router, should those components be in the components or
   views directory?
2. Should components names be capitalized like this - Participant.vue
   or participant.vue?
3. Are single word components like Participant.vue okay to use? If not,
   how should I name a component that renders information about a
   participant of a match.
4. If I want the component to use multiple words, what naming
   convention am I meant to use? ParticipantMatches.vue,
   participantMatches.vue, participant-matches.vue or
   Participant-Matches.vue?
5. If my components have some sort of hierarchy, would it be stupid to
   append the parent component name to the start of the child component
   so that related components stay grouped up in the IDE file tree?

For example:

```
Participant.vue - Parent component
ParticipantMatches.vue - Child component of Participant.vue
ParticipantMatchesStats.vue - Child component of ParticipantMatches.vue
```

The only problem I see is that component names might potentially become too big.

Comment: [Vue recommends UpperCamcelCase](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Base-component-names-strongly-recommended) for base components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a view is displaying 2 different children components based on the
> URL via a router, should those components be in the components or
> views directory?

There is not a real definition for this so it's up to you, certainly in a SPA, as it is only one page. For me personally I use place the the "views" that can be accessed via a route under views everything rendered on that view I place in components

> Should components names be capitalized like this - Participant.vue or
> participant.vue?

Vue recommends (as suggested early) https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Base-component-names-strongly-recommended

> Are single word components like Participant.vue okay to use? If not,
> how should I name a component that renders information about a
> participant of a match.

Participant.vue is basically OK, but again it's all up to you. When you have multiple component handling data of participants you could think of adding more information in the name of the component

> If I want the component to use multiple words, what naming convention
> am I meant to use? ParticipantMatches.vue, participantMatches.vue,
> participant-matches.vue or Participant-Matches.vue?

When using a component directly in the DOM (as opposed to in a string template or single-file component), we strongly recommend following the [W3C](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name) rules for custom tag names (all-lowercase, must contain a hyphen). This helps you avoid conflicts with current and future HTML elements.

> If my components have some sort of hierarchy, would it be stupid to
> append the parent component name to the start of the child component
> so that related components stay grouped up in the IDE file tree?

Place the components that belong to each other in a directory, I should not use the parent name in the component itself, If you want to reuse the component somewhere else in the future, the name doesn't make sense anymore.